# why I can't adjust Onlyoffice height on browser by changing "height" value

Tags: onlyoffice

I tried to develop ONLYOFFFICE by java. but when I open a file, onlyoffice workspace becomes so small just like here.[enter image description here][1]
and I tried to adjust it in editor.html like this.
[enter image description here][2]

and it doesn't work. by the way when I change the "width" value, the width of onlyoffice can be changed, But whatever value attached to "height", it has nothing changed.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARb32.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Dl6.png

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing height in percentage, give it in px

```
"height" : "1000px"
```